# How to disable SMTP access to certain users in Exim using Dovecot Authenticator

Tags: dovecot, exim

I need to make an Dovecot IMAP email account receive-only so that the users can browse, move, delete existing emails but without being able to send email from that account.

Sending is done via exim accepting SMTP connections from MUAs. It uses Dovecot as an authenticator like so:

```
dovecot_plain:
     driver = dovecot
     public_name = PLAIN
     server_socket = /var/run/dovecot/auth-client
     server_set_id = $auth1
```

How can I do something like:

```
   unless_login_name_is = notallowed1@mydomain.com : notallowed2@mydomain.com
```

### Edit: here's what is not working...

```
acl_smtp_mailauth = acl_check_mailauth

...

acl_check_mailauth:                                                                                                                                                                           
  deny condition = ${if eq{$authenticated_sender}{banned.user@example.com} {yes}{no}}
```

I thought it might be the condition that's wrong, but doing this:

```
acl_check_mailauth:                                                                                                                                                                           
  deny
```

also has no effect. I've read [the manual](https://www.exim.org/exim-html-current/doc/html/spec_html/ch-smtp_authentication.html#SECTauthparamail) but didn't find it helped me understand what's going on.

### Edit 2: trying `acl_smtp_auth`

As suggested by @wurtel, I tried using this ACL instead. However I am now stuck with another problem: the AUTH comes in PLAIN form which looks like

```
PLAIN <base64encodedvalue>
```

To get to the username, I need to decode it, however `${base64d:${sg{$smtp_command_argument}{^PLAIN }{}}}` retuns an empty string.

I think this is because the `<base64encodedvalue>` when decoded starts with a NUL byte!

Comment: You could define an ACL `acl_smtp_mailauth` which is run when a user authenticates, and use that to filter which users may authenticate to exim. You can test `$authenticated_sender` in that ACL.

Comment: @wurtel thanks, I've tried (and failed) at that - see edited question.

Comment: I've since read that acl_check_mailauth is only if AUTH is supplied on the MAIL SMTP command, try acl_check_auth as well. You do have exim configured to only allow authenticated users to send mail? If not, the ACL doesn't help, a deny only removes the AUTH part of the SMTP transaction.

Comment: @wurtel again, thanks, I see that mailauth is not going to work. I AM authenticating users before accepting mail. But now I've hit another brick wall (see edit 2)

Answer (score 1):

(Thanks to the comments from @wurtel which were helpful in ruling out my initial aproaches)

I've achieved this by altering `acl_smtp_auth` with the following ACL:

```
acl_check_mail:

  deny
    condition   = ${lookup{$authenticated_id}lsearch{/etc/exim4/users-not-allowed-to-send-mail}{yes}{no}}
    message     = "Sending mail is not enabled for this account"
    log_message = "Denied sending mail as '$authenticated_id'"

  # Uncomment the following to debug:
  # warn log_message = "acl_check_mail is accepting mail for '$authenticated_id'"

  accept
```

Then I have a file at `/etc/exim4/users-not-allowed-to-send-mail` with lines like

```
disabled.account@example.com
also.disabled@example.com
```

Note that `${lookup}` is helpful enough to not match an empty `$authenticated_id` with a line in the file.